# Paperclip fails on a validates_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Ok so i have a model and in that model i have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>",:tiny => "25x25>" }
end
```

when i create an user and upload a picture and not enter a name I get the expected message

```
1 error prohibited this user from being saved.
There were problems with the following fields:
    * Name can't be blank
```

But the image is gone...when i look at my console i see

```
        [paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/QK/QK+tCPT-Gx8yGDxVQbDuF++++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110113-19714-1ucz75p-0.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
        [paperclip] convert '/var/folders/QK/QK+tCPT-Gx8yGDxVQbDuF++++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110113-19714-1ucz75p-0.jpg[0]' -resize "25x25>" '/var/folders/QK/QK+tCPT-Gx8yGDxVQbDuF++++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110113-19714-1ucz75p-020110113-19714-r839l2-0' 2>/dev/null
```

but the image is gone on the new page....is there a way to preserve this image so anyone using the page doesnt have to browse for the image again

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no. This is browser behaviour that the server has no control over. If you're worried about validations elsewhere in your model causing the user to have to reselect and re-upload their images then I'd suggest making the file attachment a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

The browser resets the form when they come back to it. You might be able to simulate something that looks like a single step by uploading the file using ajax in the background, and having javascripty goodness keep the form from submitting until the file is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

A better idea might be to add client-side validations to the form, so that if the user enters invalid data, they are immediately prompted to correct it. If you're only supporting IE10+, you can use HTML5 validations, otherwise you'll have to use Javascript validations.